# mediaplaeyer id cannot be resolved into a field

Tags: java, android, button

Im trying to get a button to play a sound when i click it. I created a raw folder in the res and imported the mp3 from there my code is

```
package com.example.whothehellcares;

import android.R;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



}
    public MediaPlayer mpButtonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Music_raw);

    Button Button_main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

however the Music_raw in the media player comes up as "cannot be resolved or is not a field. I have saved and cleaned. what the heck is wrong and even if i remove import android.R; i just get an error saying that R. needs to be a method and no matter what i make it i still get that Music_raw error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing something like `com.example.whothehellcares.R` instead of `android.R`. `android.R` contains Android specific resources.